# Unable to receive GCM topic messages on iOS 9.1

Tags: objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, ios9

I wrote application which uses GCM topic massaging to receive push notifications from server. Applications works fine on iOS 8.1 but on 9.1 it registers for `registerUserNotificationSettings` and `registerForRemoteNotifications` successfully, gets APNs token and `GGLInstanceID` token successfully, Subscribes to topic successfully. But it doesnt receives messages sent on topics but it does receives messages sent directly to its registration token. I have spent a whole day debugging this but i am unable to reach any conclusion because some times it receives messages when app is running in debug mode but when i make package and transfer ipa file to device it never receives topic messages.

Comment: Can you paste your HTTP request in your question?